# How to let LaTeX forget that a class has been loaded?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

Consider the two files

```
% mydoc.tex
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

% myclass.cls
\LoadClass[x]{myclass}
```

When LaTeXing `mydoc.tex`, I get two errors (the second one after skipping the first one):

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for document class myclass.
! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.
```

This is not surprising, as LaTeX remembers the class files it has already loaded as well as the options used with each class. So it notes that the option `x` was not present with the first loading, and it refrains from loading the class a second time.

Which commands do I have to add to `myclass.cls` (before `\LoadClass`) such that LaTeX forgets that `myclass.cls` has just been loaded, as well as the options used when loading the class? If the commands work, the above example should result in a loop, as `myclass.cls` is loaded over and over again. Ideally, the patch should be robust such that it survives low level changes to LaTeX.

**Edit:** This is just a MWE, as we always request from our OPs. If you prefer to solve the real issue, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703035/different-definitions-of-commands-in-different-chapters-with-subfiles).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: "Ideally, the patch should be robust such that it survives low level changes to LaTeX." → this means you want to use only "documented interfaces" to LaTeX. Unfortunately I don't think such a task is directly possible using documented interfaces only, so maybe there's a better way to implement what you want to implement e.g. `if(no option passed) {reload class with option A}` can be implemented by `if(no option passed) {set flag A = true}`. For this, it would be helpful to explain what you're trying to implement.

Comment: "Forgetting what class it loaded" seems like the wrong answer.  You're wanting to figure out how to avoid option classing.  But I don't understand why the class `myclass` should want to load itself.  Wouldn't "result in a loop" be an outcome to avoid?

Comment: a quite creative way to increase compilation time.

Comment: @user202729 A "robust" solution is just a nice-to-have, making the solution less fragile. I have added the use case.

Comment: Ah I understood, you're the author of `subfiles` package and some internal update of LaTeX breaks your package.

Comment: Okay, to solve your X problem, I think the best solution is that currently you load the subfile by redefining `\documentclass` to be `\let\documentclass\subfiles@documentclass \LoadClass`, however this relies on the internal implementation of `\LoadClass`, it's more robust to *bypass it completely* and do something like `\def\documentclass[#1]#2{ \def\mainFileName{#1} \input{subfiles.cls} }` (technically this is not an answer to your Y problem in this question so I'm not posting it as an answer)

Comment: (and it's guaranteed to work because `\documentclass` always appear as the very first command of the subfile) (of course you may choose to check if the user forget to give the optional argument and raise error accordingly)

Comment: This is a good question. On occasion, I need to load some small amount of code from package X, which is all I need at that moment. But it must be used at that point. Then, after doing other things, package X is loaded for real. Currently I solve this by taking advantage of the LPPL, and shamelessly copying some of X code to where it is needed. As for the `\normalsize`: If you are using `fontspec` (I do not know about non-fontspec), it is possible to temporarily set `normalsize` so that the package loads, then re-set normalsize to some other value, which may be decimal.

Comment: @rallg Actually, copy-pasting is the only reliable option, if the package X doesn't allow you to solve your problem using the documented/public interface only.  I think doing the "fake-unloading" as suggested by this question will be more fragile and dependent on the implementation of package X. (but I can't really tell without a specific example)

Comment: @user202729 Bypassing LaTeX entirely is a good idea, but not trivial either: The first time, `myclass` has already been loaded by `\LoadClass`, so I can either undo it or leave it. The last class in the sequence (which will not be `myclass`) should be loaded with `\Loadclass`, so `\documentclass` would have to be redefined to check the class and take different actions depending on whether it is `myclass` again or another one. Ian Thompson's solution (or a similar one) seems to be the easier one, for the moment at least ...

Comment: @gernot I don't understand what you're talking about, in your specific use case then the documentclass being (re)loaded must be `subfiles`, so it seems my suggestion would be robust?

Comment: @user202729 No, not exactly: The last document class in the row is a real class,  and it should be loaded by `\LoadClass`, as the result should be indistinguishable from the situation where this class was loaded from the outset. The user determines what will be the next class: `\documentclass[a]{subfiles}` means that `a.tex` is loaded, and its first line may again be a line like the one above (but with `b` instead if `a`), or a regular document start.

Comment: @gernot Ah, I see, the problem happens when there's a nested `subfiles` where main file of `b` is `a`, and main file of `c` is `b`, and you compile the innermost file (`c`).  In which case, it's still possible to first check if the class file name is `subfiles`, if yes then specially handle, else fallback to `LoadClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the dirtiest hack I have ever concocted. I have no idea what it might break, and I don't like to think what @egreg will call it (though that might involve the word "disaster"). Still, you can achieve the infinite loop with the following.

```
%myclass.cls
\expandafter\let\csname ver@myclass.cls\endcsname\relax
\LoadClass[x]{myclass}
```

The first (uncommented) line tricks the test on class loading into believing that `myclass.cls` has not been loaded already. This prevents the option check from ever taking place, so it's enough to trigger the infinite loop on its own.

You can trick the option check into thinking that the original class option sequence was `x` with

```
\expandafter\def\csname opt@myclass.cls\endcsname{x}
```

but I don't think that's ever useful because after `LaTeX` simply ignores reloading attempts where the options match.

Use at your own risk...

Comment: What's the difference between a calamity and a disaster? If [insert name of politician here] falls in the river, it's a calamity; if somebody dives in order to save them, it's a disaster.

Comment: @egreg Witty. To me, the situation seems different, though: An old tool that is dear to some people has gotten a scratch, and Ian provided a patch.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be my solution. Re dirty hack: Since I took over the maintenance of subfiles, I never got out of the dirt again ;-)

Comment: @egreg Even if you don't find `subfiles` package useful, someone else in the world must have had (otherwise the package wouldn't have been written in the first place). Do you have any better solution for fixing `subfiles` package in newer LaTeX version?

Comment: @user202729 Did I say anything about `subfiles`?